# Divergence of a series containing primes

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Is there an easy proof showing that the series $1/p$, where $p$ changes over prime numbers, is divergent?

Comment: Mertens theorem

Comment: The standard proof due to Euler is take the logarithmic derivative of the zeta function, expand each term of the infinite product into a series, then show all the terms of the form $1/p^{ns}$ for $n\geq 2$ converge. What's left over is a sum over $1/p^s$. This must diverge, because the Riemann zeta function diverges as $s$ approaches 1 from the right, because the harmonic series does.

Answer (score 1):

The proof by Tom Apostol (section 1.6 in his Intro to Analytic Number Th) is clean. If it converges then we can find $k$ so that if $p_m$ is the $m$th prime then the sum from $k+1$ onwards is less than $\frac{1}{2}$. Let $Q$ the product of $p_1,\dots,p_k$. Consider the numbers $1+nQ$ for $n=1,2,\dots$. None of these is divisible by any of the first $k$ primes. Therefore all the prime factors of $1+nQ$ occur amongst the later primes. Now it is easy to see that $\frac{1}{1+nQ}$ converges. Contradiction.